# AWK filter x Group by Hour

Tags: apache, awk

I try to get the hits on an access_log by hour, but inside I have some lines that I want to ignore (css/js/etc...)

If I run:

```
grep "31/Mar" access_log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk  -F: '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c
```

Have the expected result, like:

> ```
> 105 03
> 177 04
> 153 05
> 144 06
> ```

But if I add the filter :

```
grep "31/Mar" access_log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk  -F '!/.pdf|.css|.png|.jpg|.js/': '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c
```

The result is one line...

> 7496

What I doing wrong ?

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts. Could you please post few samples of logs in your question that will give us better idea of your question. Thank you.

Comment: `-F '!/.pdf|.css|.png|.jpg|.js/':` doesn't make sense - that's a condition, not a regexp. As @Ravinder said, though, please post a [mcve] that contains concise, testable sample input (contents of `access_log`) and expected output.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 is a common log file from apache that I want to read

Comment: @EdMorton any standard access_log can be used and considered as a sample for the objective here, the first command that I show works fine and you reproduce it on a access_log normally

Comment: Don't assume that those awk experts interested in helping you have such a "standard access_log" lying around or even now what "apache" is. When you ask a question you have to provide sample input and the expected output given that input so we have something we can test a potential solution against. Otherwise you're greatly restricting the set of people willing/able to help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to write:

```
awk  -F':' '!/\.(pdf|css|png|jpg|js)$/{print $2}'
```

but there's other issues in your script we could help you with given a MCVE.

Comment: not work, because the file loaded  must be passed as a literal to split the parameters and not quoted string.

Comment: I've no idea what that means, you're going to have to do better with asking your question for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

All this long pipeline can be done in a single `awk` as well like this:

```sh
awk -F: '!/\.(pdf|css|png|jpg|js)$/ && /31\/Mar/ {++freq[$4]}
END {for (f in freq) print f, freq[f]}' access_log

12 8
13 2
14 1
```

Comment: Thanks but I found my mistake...if I refine grep, it will work

Comment: `cut` and `grep` should not be used if a swiss-knife tool `awk` is already in use.  If it can be done in a single comment why complicate and make it slow by running 6 commands in a pipeline?

Answer (score -1):

My error...
After tests, I notice the problem was grep.
If I refine grep I can ignore lines and apply awk under the result correctly.

```
grep -Ev ".js|.css|.jpg|.png|.pdf" access_log | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d] -f1 | awk  -F : '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c
```

Comment: Your grep command doesn't do what you think it does so it will fail for some input and you don't need grep + 2*cut + 3 pipes, etc. when you're using awk.